# React Hooks showing inconsistent behaviour

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I wanted to get a feel for react hooks and was trying them out by making a normal todo list with adding and removing capabilities but I have come across an annoying behaviour and I do not know the logic behind it.

```
 const handleDeleteTodos = (event) => {
    todos.splice(event.target.name, 1);
    setTodos(todos)
    window.localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
  };
```

So the code above does delete the element, I know this because when I reload the page, the element is gone. But it doesn't re-render like the add todo function. While the code below works.

```
const handleDeleteTodos = (event) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(event.target.name, 1); 
    setTodos(newTodos)
    window.localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
  };
```

I only difference I see is the object destructuring aspect of the code.

I just wanted to know what is the logic behind this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing [stale props](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function).

[Use the function form of `setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) to modify objects without that caveat (since the reference to that object is passed to you by React).

```
const handleDeleteTodos = (event) => {
  const { name } = event.target; // important to copy the name before `setTodos`, since react reuses events
  setTodos((todos) => {
    const newTodos = [...todos];
    newTodos.splice(name, 1);
    return newTodos;
  });
};
```

Also, use `useEffect` to modify `localStorage` based on `todos`, since it literally is a side effect of state being modified, instead of doing it manually in each modification function.

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]);
```

Answer (score 0):

React only rerenders if the reference to the object on state has changed (or if it's scalar, the value itself).
You must create a new object and set it on state.

The first example uses the same reference, so React has no idea anything changed.
The second example uses a new reference.

Comment: Oh, so setState only rerenders when the object is a new one, now I understand, thanks

Comment: Yep, same as props.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

`Array.prototype.splice` does an in-place ***mutation*** of the array.

[Array.prototype.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

> The `splice()` method changes the contents of an array by removing or
> replacing existing elements and/or adding new elements ***in place***.
> To access part of an array without modifying it, see `slice()`

You are mutating the current state and then saving the same reference back into state.

```
const handleDeleteTodos = (event) => {
  todos.splice(event.target.name, 1); // <-- mutation
  setTodos(todos); // <-- same state reference
  window.localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
};
```

Because a new array reference is never created, React doesn't see that state was ever updated.

## Solution

Creating a new array reference allows React to use a shallow reference equality check and rerender.

```
const handleDeleteTodos = (event) => {
  const newTodos = [...todos]; // <-- shallow copy into new reference
  newTodos.splice(event.target.name, 1); // <-- mutate copy
  setTodos(newTodos); // <-- save new reference into state

  window.localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
};
```

A more conventional method is to use `Array.prototype.filter` to shallow copy the array ***and*** remove the element at the same time.

```
const handleDeleteTodos = (event) => {
  const newTodos = todos.filter((_, index) => event.target.name !== index);

  setTodos(newTodos);

  window.localStorage.setItem('Todos', JSON.stringify(newTodos));
};
```